# How to convert ints in a list of strings into ints in python?

Tags: python

For example I have a list of strings:

```
lst = ["hello","ASKDJ","1","4","xcvs"]
```

How would I convert the ints in that list of strings into ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [string.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

> `str.isdigit()`
>
> Return true if all characters in the string are digits
>   and there is at least one character, false otherwise.

```
def to_ints_if_possible(seq):
    return [int(s) if s.isdigit() else s for s in seq]
lst = ["hello","ASKDJ","1","4","xcvs"]
converted = to_ints_if_possible(lst)
```

Comment: Thanks your one was the most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Conditionally convert the elements to integers incase all the string characters are digits. The string method [str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) returns true if all the elements of the string are digits.

```
>>> [int(elem ) if elem.isdigit() else elem for elem in lst]
['hello', 'ASKDJ', 1, 4, 'xcvs']
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any ints in that list, just strings. You can convert some of the strings to integers with the function `int`.

```
lst = ["hello","ASKDJ","1","4","xcvs"]

for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    try:
        foo = int(item)
        lst[index] = foo
    except ValueError, e:
        print("Item " + item + " cannot be turned into a number!")
        print(e)
        continue
```

You get the following output:

```
>>> 
Item hello cannot be turned into a number!
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
Item ASKDJ cannot be turned into a number!
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ASKDJ'
Item xcvs cannot be turned into a number!
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'xcvs'
```

Now try printing the list:

```
>>> lst
['hello', 'ASKDJ', 1, 4, 'xcvs']
```

Comment: This way you would even accept "-12" as input, since it is a valid int even if it does not contain only digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert(L):
    for i, elem in enumerate(L):
        if not elem.isdigit():
            continue
        L[i] = int(elem)

In [12]: L = ["hello","ASKDJ","1","4","xcvs"]

In [13]: convert(L)

In [14]: L
Out[14]: ['hello', 'ASKDJ', 1, 4, 'xcvs']
```

Comment: Do you actually need to do this `all(char.isdigit() for char in elem)`? What is wrong in `elem.isdigit()`?

Comment: @Abhijit: I didn't know I could do that. Thanks :)